# How to load a remote content into a dialog box with jquery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-domain

I'm trying to load a remote content of my site with jquery, but I constantly get an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   'anylink_here'
>   Origin null is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#checkout').submit(function(e){
        //prevent default behavior and hide possibly existing pop-up
        e.preventDefault();
        //process request
        var form = this;
        var url = form.action;
        var dialog = $('<div id="lightbox_dialog"></div>').appendTo('body');
        // load remote content
        dialog.load(
            url,
            function (response, status, xhr){
                dialog.html(response);
            });
        dialog.dialog();
        //prevent the browser to follow the link
        return false;
    });
});
```

And a form code:

```
<form id="checkout" action='http://me.me/' method='get'>
        <input type="image" class="class1" onclick="this.form.action='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample'" title="Title" value="" src="http://4cornersautoloan.com/images/SmallButton.gif">
    </form>
```

I also need to do it for the same domain but from http to https.

Comment: see this thread, I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106993/ajax-cross-sub-domain-requests

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142779/help-with-getting-json-format-data-from-external-website/4142817#4142817

Comment: and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828982/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-an-url-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible basically because ajax doesn't support cross-domain request and http to https will be regarded as one.

Answer (score 1):

You will need server-side code on your same domain to perform the fetching for you.

Comment: What I have for this task is JS, nothing more.

Comment: @den-javamaniac Then sadly (or happily, if your intent was nefarious :) you are out of luck. (Unless the server supports JSONP.)

Answer (score 0):

How about iframing it in?

```
<body>
        <p id="open">Click to open</p>
        <div id="dialog" title="window title">
            <p><iframe src="popup.html" ></iframe></p>
        </div>
        <script>

            $('div#dialog').dialog({
                autoOpen : false,
                show : "scale",
                hide : "scale",

            });
            $('#open').click (function (event)
                {
                    if ($("#dialog").dialog("isOpen"));
                    else $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```