# jQuery.get() fails with full url

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var url = "/example/somelink";
jQuery.get( url, params, callback);  //works fine

var url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
jQuery.get( url, params, callback);  //fails!
```

when I give the full URL of a site, get() fails...any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: cross domain workaround in this thread with jsonp: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106993/ajax-cross-sub-domain-requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access a remote domain like this, only your own domain.  The difference is the domain, not the full vs relative URL.

It's the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that's blocking you here, you have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) to get data directly or proxy the request through your own domain.

Answer (score 1):

If by "fails", you mean that you're unable to access the HTML you hoped to receive, this is prevented by the browser for security reasons.

You can manipulate the response only if it comes from the same domain from which the request is sent.

Comment: I am new to javascript...so, forgive my ignorance.

Comment: oops! didnt complete it yet.  Actually I am debugging thru firebug.  and i am able to see the GET request being sent.  but then it becomes red and there is nothing in the 'response' tab.

Comment: Actually though the GET request link becomes red, there is a 200 OK next to it.  So i guess as you said the response is coming back but I cannot see it?

Comment: @hese - that's *exactly* what happens, please read the same origin policy link in my answer for a full explanation.

Comment: @hese - @Nick is correct. You'll get a successful response code, but you'll have a null response content. This is a security measure. I think you'd have to use a server-side solution to overcome it. If your server does the fetch for you, then passes the result to you, then your AJAX request is being made to the original domain.

Comment: @Nick, @Patrick - actually this other server (say server2) that I am querying is also ours.  So is there a way I can do a DNS mapping (where?) so that the two domain names match?  And will I be able to see the result then?

Comment: @hese - If the browser goes to the same `domain.tld`, say they're both `site.com` then yes, it'll work, if the domain doesn't match...it's a no go.

Comment: @hese - I'm certain you could use a reverse proxy, or have one server forward the request to the other (same thing, I guess). The important thing is that the request is able to be sent to the exact same domain as that from which the page was loaded.